# Check to see if a cell consists only of vowels or consonants Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a macro to see if the cells in a column are consisting only of consonants or only of vowels, and if they do color the entire row with yellow. I have these two functions to check the count of consonants:

```
Function ConsonantCount(cons As String) As Integer
Dim Str
Dim KCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Chr As String

Str = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
KCount = 0
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
    Chr = UCase(Mid(Str, i, 1))
    If Not Chr Like "[AEIOU]" Then
      KCount = KCount + 1
End If
Next i
cons = KCount
End Function
```

Respective vowels:

```
Function VowelCount(vowl As String) As Integer
Dim Str
Dim KCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim Chr As String

Str = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
KCount = 0
For i = 1 To Len(Str)
  Chr = UCase(Mid(Str, i, 1))
  If Chr Like "[AEIOU]" Then
    KCount = KCount + 1
End If
Next i
vowl = KCount
End Function
```

Then I'm using the functions to see if there's 0 consonants/vowels for two different columns M and N :

```
Dim iix As Long, FFX As Long
With Sheets("JP")
FFX = .Range("M" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
For iix = 1 To FFX
    If ConsonantCount(.Range("M" & iix)) = 0 Then
        .Rows(iix).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
    If ConsonantCount(.Range("N" & iix)) = 0 Then
        .Rows(iix).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
    If VowelCount(.Range("M" & iix)) = 0 Then
        .Rows(iix).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
    If VowelCount(.Range("N" & iix)) = 0 Then
        .Rows(iix).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If
Next iix
End With
```

I really need some guidance, fairly new to VBA, Thank You in advance!

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? Do the functions work? Consider also that unless you need to know discrete counts, you should exit those functions on the *first* occurrence -- if all you need is boolean true/false (e.g., only vowels = consonantcount=0, only consonants = vowelcount = 0).

Comment: What is happening with the code above? Are you getting an error? A result that is different from expected?

Comment: Also avoid using reserved or semi-reserved keywords as identifiers `Chr` is a function call which returns a string/character from an ascii code.

Comment: There is no error, but the rows that should be colored are not, but it doesn't color miss-color the others as well..

Comment: If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @Brian M Stafford Will do, thank you for pointing it out, I do want to help in any way I can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if a cell contains only vowels or only consonants, you would check the length of the cell text against the vowel or consonant count.  For example, to see if a cell is only consonants you would do this:

```
Len(.Range("M" & iix)) = ConsonantCount(.Range("M" & iix))
```

You would also need to check for empty cells so they don't get highlighted.  Keeping these ideas in mind, I reworked your code a little so it works how I think you want it to work.

```
Function ConsonantCount(cons As String) As Integer
   'Dim Str
   Dim KCount As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim Chr As String

   'Str = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
   KCount = 0

   For i = 1 To Len(cons)
       Chr = UCase(Mid(cons, i, 1))
       If Not Chr Like "[AEIOU]" Then
         KCount = KCount + 1
       End If
   Next i

   ConsonantCount = KCount
End Function

Function VowelCount(vowl As String) As Integer
   'Dim Str
   Dim KCount As Integer
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim Chr As String

   'Str = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
   KCount = 0

   For i = 1 To Len(vowl)
     Chr = UCase(Mid(vowl, i, 1))
     If Chr Like "[AEIOU]" Then
       KCount = KCount + 1
     End If
   Next i

   VowelCount = KCount
End Function

Sub Test()
   Dim iix As Long
   Dim FFX As Long

   With Sheets("JP")
      FFX = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      For iix = 1 To FFX
          If Len(.Range("M" & iix)) > 0 Then
            If Len(.Range("M" & iix)) = ConsonantCount(.Range("M" & iix)) Or Len(.Range("M" & iix)) = VowelCount(.Range("M" & iix)) Then
                .Rows(iix).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
          End If

          If Len(.Range("N" & iix)) > 0 Then
            If Len(.Range("N" & iix)) = ConsonantCount(.Range("N" & iix)) Or Len(.Range("N" & iix)) = VowelCount(.Range("N" & iix)) Then
                .Rows(iix).Interior.Color = vbYellow
            End If
          End If
      Next iix
   End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Is the issue you are seeing related to it highlighting lines it shouldn't? This is because your functions should end with

`ConsonantCount = Kcount`

and

`VowelCount = Kcount`

(Instead of 'cons = Kcount' and 'vowl = Kcount').

In VBA you use the name of the function to return a value.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit Shrivallabha. I'm Still trying to used to this :)

Comment: You need to use backticks (`) and not single quote('). Easy to mix up :)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to check letter by letter.  To see if a cell contains all consonants or vowels, you can do something like (function returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'case insensitive compares

Function AllConsonants(R As Range) As Boolean
    Dim sPat As String

sPat = WorksheetFunction.Rept("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]", Len(R.Text))
AllConsonants = R.Text Like sPat And Len(R.Text) > 0

End Function

Function AllVowels(R As Range) As Boolean
    Dim sPat As String

sPat = WorksheetFunction.Rept("[aeiou]", Len(R.Text))
AllVowels = R.Text Like sPat And Len(R.Text) > 0

End Function
```